# Why did it stop at the 3rd row after I selected another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops, do-while

I was testing my coding by deleting and adding more data, and that's when I realised that something went wrong with my coding. Initially, I started my coding with 3 person under the "LEAVE" section.

So I tried deleting people off the section, the coding still works. It was when I added one more person under that section, then I realised my coding did not work. When I changed the data from 3 to 4 person, it still stopped at the 3rd person. It did not continue the loop to detect the 4th person.

I tested and realised that it was when I started with

```
Sheets("Cash").Select
```

onwards that it didn't work.

Without that, the loop still works and it can detect the 4th person.

```
Do While Cells(ShiftRowName, 1) <> ""
    Set ShiftName = Sheets("Shift Roster").Cells(ShiftRowName, ShiftColName)

    If ShiftName = "" Or IsEmpty(ShiftName) Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        'When the following coding was added,
        'It stopped detecting at the 3rd person.
        Sheets("Cash").Select

        Range("C1").Select
        Cells.Find("Name").Activate
        r2 = ActiveCell.Row

        CashRowName = r2 + 1

        Do While Cells(CashRowName, 1) <> ""
            Set CashName = Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, CashColName)

            If CashName = "" Or IsEmpty(CashName) Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                MsgBox CashName
                MsgBox ShiftName

                End If
            CashRowName = CashRowName + 1
        Loop

        End If
    ShiftRowName = ShiftRowName + 1
Loop
```

Any possible to solve this ?

EDIT:

Because of Forward Ed's enlightenment, I found the answer to my problem. Thank you.

I used the following code

```
With Sheets("Cash")
    Set FindRow = .Range("C:C").Find(What:="Name", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
Dim FindRowNumber As Long
CashRowName = FindRow.Row
```

Comment: you need to return to the sheet with your sheet with the list after you are done doing what you are doing on the "Cash" sheet.  Alternatively its better to just manipulate your CASH sheet without actually selecting it.

Comment: so is the `Do While Cells(CashRowName, 1)` loop to act on "Shift Roster" sheet cells?

Comment: Yes, just add Sheets("Cash") would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        'When the following coding was added,
        'It stopped detecting at the 3rd person.

        r2 = Sheets("Cash").Range("C1").Find("Name").row
        'not sure if the above coding will actually work,
        'but it avoids switching sheets and tries to work
        'directly on worksheet "CASH".  

        CashRowName = r2 + 1
```

That is a small snippet of your code edited.  I am pretty sure my syntax is off.  The gist is it avoids changing worksheets in the middle of your loop.  Also, using select repeatedly will slow down your code and should be avoided.